# Transpose in ORACLE SQL (Convert 6 columns into 3 Columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've an output like the below.

[image]

I want that to be converted into the below

[image]

Where ID is the count of TOTAL, HIGH, SENT, WAITING, DATE. I have been contemplating for a while and couldn't get what I want. Can any one please help in ORACLE SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (cdate, total, high, sent, waiting, loc) as
  2    (select 1012018, 23, 4, 35, 45, 13456 from dual union all
  3     select 1212018, 74, 2, 77, 82, 98765 from dual
  4    ),
  5  temp as
  6    (select 5 rn, loc, cdate as value from test union all
  7     select 1 rn, loc, total          from test union all
  8     select 2 rn, loc, high           from test union all
  9     select 3 rn, loc, sent           from test union all
 10     select 4 rn, loc, waiting        from test
 11    )
 12  select rn, value, loc
 13  from temp
 14  order by loc, rn;

        RN      VALUE        LOC
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         23      13456
         2          4      13456
         3         35      13456
         4         45      13456
         5    1012018      13456
         1         74      98765
         2          2      98765
         3         77      98765
         4         82      98765
         5    1212018      98765

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried to mimic to my problem. But still, I'm having issues.

Comment: I can't paste all my code here. hence splitting it for your reference.                              
with test (tot, se, hi, re, tim, p_id) as
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loc_t B GROUP BY B.r_id) AS se,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loc_t B GROUP BY B.r_id) AS hi,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loc_t B GROUP BY B.r_id) AS re,
((SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(B.tim),'DDMMYYYY') FROM loc_t B WHERE B.r_id=A.r_id GROUP BY B.r_id)) AS tim,
r_id FROM loc_t A WHERE TRUNC(A.tim)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND A.r_id IN (SELECT LOC FROM LOC WHERE zo=100) GROUP BY r_id
),

Comment: temp as
(
select 1 fi, p_id, tot from test union all
select 2 fi, p_id, se from test union all
select 3 fi, p_id, hi from test union all
select 4 fi, p_id, re from test union all
select 5 fi, p_id, tim as value from test
)
select fi, value, p_id
from temp
order by p_id, fi;

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thanks for your guidance, Littlefoot.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it. BTW, if you have to post code you wrote, it is best to edit the original question. As you can see, posting it as a comment doesn't look well.